# How can I change the unit test directory in VS 2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

by which I mean the directory returned by

```
   this.TestContext.TestDir
```

inside a unit test.

Only **VS2012** is concerned.

I tried VS test settings, but the folder one can configure did not affect the TestDir value and in addition MS highly recommends not to use .testsettings files anymore.

We consider setting this directory manually from an environment variable that has to be set up on build/dev machines, better workarounds also welcome.

Comment: Could you make an example why this is neccessary to use for your tests?

Comment: Being able to specify the test output directory should be elementary, surprised you ask for an example. The unit tests for our file api create and delete *many* files. On my local dev machine I want to create these files on my RAM disk. On the build machine the directory would be different.

But there is more: In VS2012, the test output directory grows with every test run, the limit functionality, keep only the last n runs, was omitted. So my local SSD drive gets filled up wth test files and I have to manually delete the test files by hand.

Comment: I might be wrong, but did you consider this perspective: running integration tests in dedicated environment that can be reset to some known state prior to running the tests?

Comment: Well that would be a way, but running the tests as unit tests inside vs is very convenient and the vs2012 test runner is also extremely fast. it is just that ms ommitted many features that were available before. until the new test runner is complete again the question is for "best workaround". before running tests externally, an environment variable will be more convenient.